# Not sure why my class myhyperlink is not coming through to actual link

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I create a SASS style as follows:

```
a .myhyperlink {
  color: #ce4dd6;
  &:hover { color: #ffb3ff; }
  &:visited { color: #c458cb; }
}
```

which compiles to

```
/* line 64, ../Sass/svcc.scss */
a .myhyperlink {
  color: #ce4dd6;
}
/* line 66, ../Sass/svcc.scss */
a .myhyperlink:hover {
  color: #ffb3ff;
}
/* line 67, ../Sass/svcc.scss */
a .myhyperlink:visited {
  color: #c458cb;
}
```

I was hoping that it then work on this

```
<a  class="myhyperlink" href="/VolunteerForJob" >Volunteer Page</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to match element with a specific class, you can't make a space between, like `a .myhyperlink` because it means all children of `a` element with class `myhyperlink` (that children). If you want to match an element `a` with `myhyperlink` class you have to write like this `a.myhyperlink`.

And if you want to use more classes on an single element: `a.one.two.three` - that means `a` element with class `.one` and `.two` and `.three`.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have it written write now it's targeting elements with a class of .myhperlink INSIDE anchor links.

You need `a.myhyperlink` (no space)